flutter units of measurement
old question, what is unit of measurement in flutter? online chatter (eg SO 2018) says something like "logical pixels" or "density independent pixels". official docs also mention this lingo (eg in Android section of docs), but never explicitly commit or define it. apparently there used to be clarification in Material class docs, but it's not there now.
according to material docs device independent pixel is 160 dp = 1 inch.
this is honored on android (eg pixel 7 emulator), MediaQuery reports dimensions just about consistent with 160dp/in.
however on iOS this seems a little off. for instance iPad 10th gen specs (2360 x 1640, 264ppi, 8.93 x 6.21 inch) is reported as 1180 x 820 by MediaQuery (and an accurate devicePixelRatio: 2.0 with it btw). that's 132 dp = 1 inch, not 160.
I was expecting width: 160 to result in physical 1 inch across device.
what is the definition (preferably documented) of measurement units in flutter?

similar results on iPad Pro 1st gen in debug mode. ends up 132 dp = 1 inch
